# Fill Remaining Column Width in DataGrid if Needed WPF

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a data grid control in a WPF app that has 5 static columns with set absolute widths declared in the XAML of the view.

- Column 1 width = 50
- Column 2 width = 50
- Column 3 width = 75
- Column 4 width = 75
- Column 5 width = 75

Then, in the code behind for my view, I am dynamically generating more columns based on a query result coming from the DB (inserting them after the 5th column).  This number could be anything from 1 to N.  Each of these dynamic columns has a width of 100.

Finally, back in the XAML I have a final static column with an absolute `MinWidth`

- Column (*Last*) MinWidth = 200

This structure works great when the number of generating columns is greater than 3 (*NOTE*, my window has a set width but can be changed by the user).  When the number of dynamic columns is less than or equal to 3 then the *Last* column's width does not properly fill the remaining space of the data grid - it cuts off at 200 (which is expected) making it look like there is an additional column with no header when in reality it is just the remaining space of the `DataGridRow` in the data grid.

I need the *Last* column to fill the remaining space only if needed.  If I set the width to "*", then it crunches all the other columns to fit within the width of the data grid.  The user needs a horizontal scrollbar to be able to adequately see the values in the grid.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

**NOTE**: I am using `DataGridTemplateColumn` to build the data grid, both in the XAML and in the code-behind.

Comment: set MinWidth for every column (equal to Width)? then `*` on the last column won't shrink them

Comment: @ASh, you are a genius.  It worked.  Thanks a bunch!